# How can I display multiple metrics on a New Relic dashboard without using a wildcard?

Tags: newrelic

I've got a custom New Relic plugin, for which I'm trying to tweak the dashboards.  I'd like to make a query execution time graph that shows only min/median/max time.  However, I have 6 metrics available to me about query execution time:

```
requests-status-summary/max-seconds[sec]
requests-status-summary/mean-seconds[sec]
requests-status-summary/median-seconds[sec]
requests-status-summary/min-seconds[sec]
requests-status-summary/ninetieth-percentile-seconds-seconds[sec]
requests-status-summary/standard-dev-seconds[sec]
```

So if I match on `requests-status-summary/*[sec]`, I get all 6 of those, which is more than I want.  I tried matching on `requests-status-summary/m*[sec]`, which got me a hilarious graph displaying "In", "Ean", "Edian", and "Ax" -- besides the trying-to-be-too-smart labels, it includes mean, which I'd rather not include in this graph.

It looks like if you're not using a wildcard, your only option is to graph just one metric.  I'd just like to provide the names of the three metrics I want, something like this:

```
requests-status-summary/(min|median|max)-seconds[sec]
```

...or in some similar regex form, or even by just spelling out all three.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently New Relic only supports matching wildcards.

Since you already have the data, you could send it a second time with a different label that would match a wildcard.

Example:

```
req-status-summary/max-seconds[sec]
req-status-summary/median-seconds[sec]
req-status-summary/min-seconds[sec]
```

This would allow you to match on just these names by matching `req-status-summary/*` which shouldn't be too much trouble since you've already collected the data.